# Multiple person possession with a pronoun

Tags: possessive-pronouns

How do you handle multiple person possession with a pronoun?

For instance, "This organization has been near and dear to *my and Simon's hearts* for many years"

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I'd go with "mine and Simon's hearts".

> This organization has been near and dear to mine and Simon's hearts for many years.

The reasoning behind it is tricky. If you wanted to use "my" instead of "mine", it'd probably be best to do it like:

> This organization has been near and dear to my, as well as Simon's, heart for many years.